# Как компонентами Delphi подключиться к CallBack Api vk.com?

Tags: delphi, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api, callback

Представление о работе с серверами посредством Delphi особо не имею, только http api запросы более менее.

В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api?f=1.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20Callback%20API) сказано, что CallBack Api посылаются на мною созданный сервер Post запросом, и я должен возвращать код 200 ок

Как реализовать такой сервер на Delphi?

[Здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-networks/thread2163460.html) есть совет использовать idHTTPServer

Я пока не имею опыта работы с этим компонентом, прошу показать, как можно это сделать?

[Здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/326898/) пример неплохой, но он для стороннего сервера, а к нему обращаться еще более геморройно, да и к тому же все на питоне

Задача - получить мгновенно уведомление о том, что вышла запись в группе.
Через обычные HTTP Api сделал, но как только появились новые пользователи - сразу посыпались ограничения на запросы в вк.

Comment: В общем-то примерно придумал, как с помощью сервера, описанного в последнем примере сделать, но для этого придется изучить питоху

Comment: Суть решения с помощью того сервера: он будет принимать callback api от вк и сохранять данные последнего запроса от вк. 

А приложение Delphi будет к нему обращаться раз в секунду и получать эту сохраненную запись. 

С помощью питона на самом сервере думаю это удастся)

Comment: Restclient
Restrequest
Restresponse

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за перечисление идентиферов?